# Trying to convert a php curl script to python using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to python and am trying to re-write a php script I have in Python using the requests library. I'm having a hard time, though.

The script basically logs into a specific website using curl that requires a user/pass. PHP code below:

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";   

$loginurl = "http://www.example.com/login";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12)     Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7";

$ch = curl_init(); 

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

// curl options 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginurl);

// start session and get cookies 
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

//set params
$fields = array();
$fields['p'] = "";
$fields['dest'] = "";
$fields['username'] = $username;
$fields['password'] = $password;

$loginurl   = "https://www.example.com/login";

// set postfields 
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 

// set to login url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginurl); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

// perform login
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And this is my python code:

```
import requests

class Login():

def Login():
    username = "user"
    password = "pass"

    with requests.Session() as s:
        cookiePath = "cookie.txt"
        loginUrl = "http://www.example.com/login"
        headers = {"Accept": "*/*", "Connection": "Keep-Alive"}

        resp = s.get(loginUrl)

        params = {"p": "", "dest": "", "username": username, "password": password}
        loginUrl = "https://www.example.com/login"

        resp = s.post(loginUrl, params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login()
```

I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong. While debugging I"m printing out the header and the status code and it looks ok. I read somewhere that the requests library handles cookies for you, so I'm assuming I don't have to do anything with them, but I'm not sure. However, I have a feeling that's where things are going wrong. Does anything stand out?

Comment: You are defining a headers `dict` but not using it. You also omitted the User Agent header from the python version. You can check `resp.history` to see if any redirects were issued. Other than that, you could check the logs on the login target app if you have access to them.

Comment: Also did you mean `if __name__ == '__main__':  Login().Login()` ? The class `Login` has a method `Login` that does the actual work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would be the exact issue, but you do not seem to be sending the `headers` to the request , and neither are you setting the user-agent in the headers. Try doing this -

```
headers = {"Accept": "*/*", "Connection": "Keep-Alive", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12)     Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7"}

resp = s.post(loginUrl, params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I included this, still not able to log in.

Comment: try printing the resp you get from that, is it status `200` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your php file, you are passing some cookies in the request that are stored in a file. But in your python implementation you didn't pass the cookies (nor the headers). I think the simplest way for your case is to put the cookies directly into your code as a dictionary, like this :

```
cookies = {'key': 'value'}

resp = s.post(loginUrl, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); ? That is necessary for the php script to work. I just tried something similar with requests using resp = s.get(loginUrl, allow_redirects = True), but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: And I tried saving the cookies, but the cookie is being set as guest, which isn't correct and means I'm not getting logged in.

Comment: Requests follows redirects by default http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history